# Grails @DelegateAsync and dependency injection

Tags: spring, grails, asynchronous

I'm trying to use @DelegateAsync and running into some problems.

My setup looks pretty much like this:

```
@DelegateAsync(SynchronousService)
class AsyncService extends BaseService {}

class SynchronousService extends BaseService {}

abstract class BaseService {
  def grailsApplication
}
```

It seems that grailsApplication and other beans are never injected into SynchronousService. Should they be? AsyncService has everything wired up as I'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this might do the trick, though now I need to figure out why I'm hitting Async execution errors in GPars:

```
class AsyncService extends BaseService {
   @DelegateAsync SynchronousService synchronousService
}
```